# Woocommerce FIlter Product using color and Category?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to integrate the woocommerce rest APIs with my Applications. All the defaults operations like get all products, get products by category etc are working perfectly fine.

but how i apply color filter in my code.?

bellow is my code.

```
$data = array(
  'category' => $category_ids,
  'attribute' => 'Options',
  'attribute_term' => 'Blue',
  'per_page' => 100,
  'page' => 1
  );
$temp = ($woocommerce->get('products', $data));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to append 'pa' before your attribute name. 
so if your using 'color' attribute then it is going to be 'pa_color'.And pass attribute_term id instead of slug or name in 'attribute_term'.

**After Correction**

```
$data = array(
      'category' => $category_ids,
      'attribute' => 'pa_color',
      'attribute_term' => '27',
      'per_page' => 100,
      'page' => 1
      );
    $temp = ($woocommerce->get('products', $data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the WooCommerce forums?

Try https://www.woobeginner.com/woocommerce-support-forum/
or https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce